# Salesforce noobie - where are the crud pages for custom objects?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am a very newbie to SF so pardon my ignorance. I am doing the trailheads and logged into developers org. There I quickly created a custom object with some fields. Now how do I get a CRUD page for the custom object. I have been looking through the documentation and trailheads but I finding everything except this simple step. Can someone please suggest how I can get a CRuD page automatically generated from custom object that I can use to add edit and delete records?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [Create a Tab](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/customize-the-ui-for-a-recruiting-app/create-tab-review-object) for your custom object. This tab can be exposed in both Salesforce Classic and Lightning and allows you to create a new record in the object, view list views, and so on.